# How to create a apple watch project using phone gap

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am new on phonegap .I want to develop a project for Apple watch. How to develop a project for Apple Watch using phonegap ?  What is step to follow ?
Can i convert simple phonegap ios project in apple watch , is it possible then how ? if not so why ?

Comment: There is at least 3 different questions in here, try to search a bit on google, I'm sure you'll find an answer to each of them ! Then if you struggle with code, or something specific, S/O can help you !

Comment: Thanks @AlexandreBeaudet. I understood we can't develop phonegap app for Apple watch . But can i convert ios app in Apple watch app . Which steps should i follow ?

Answer (score 3):

You have to create a typical cordova project and have to use one of these plugins:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-apple-watch

https://github.com/Telerik-Verified-Plugins/AppleWatch

The second one gives you some more options, but both are limited.

There is no way to create a webview based app for the watch, because the watch does not have a webview.

If you need more features, you have to write your own native watch app.

Comment: If we write a native watch app, so what happens if we build the ios app, because of Info.plist file will be reloaded? In fact, I tried to create a native watch app, but then I got an error: "Could not find *-Info.plist file, or config.xml file" and I can't build the ios app anymore. Could please tell me any solution for that? Thanks